# $\Vert f \Vert_p$  is continuous in $p$?

Tags: real-analysis

When $f$ is a Lebesgue measurable function, is $\Vert f \Vert_p$ continuous in $p$, when $p$ is in a set such that f belongs to $L_p$? If yes, how to show that? Thanks!

Yes. It is an exercise taken from Rudin's book. I have spent quite a while thinking but got no idea.

Comment: Is this homework?  What have you tried?

Comment: Yes. I have tried to use composition of continous functions still being continous, but the integral is there...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may not be the answer you are looking for, but:

Using Holder's inequality you can show that the map $p^{-1}\mapsto \|f\|_p$ is **log-convex**. Now just use the fact that any convex function on an interval is continuous.

Comment: Thanks, Willie! It looks like the right way to go.

Answer (score 1):

So you're asking about $p \mapsto \left( \int_X |f|^p d\mu \right)^{1/p}$. Isn't this clearly a composition of continuous functions?

First $p \mapsto |f|^p$ (no hints, but this should be pretty easy), then the Lebesgue integral (hint: it's a linear map between the Banach space $L^p(X,\mu)$ and $\mathbb{R}$. Which linear maps are continuous?), and finally $x \mapsto x^{1/p}$.

Comment: Thanks, Kahen. I thought similar way at first but got stuck at the integral. Looks like your way is correct as well...